# Image_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've written this:

```
<div id="Table_01">
    <div id="SAVEonSHIRTS-website-homepage-01">
        <image_tag("SAVEonSHIRTS_website_homepage_01.png")>
    </div>
    <div id="SAVEonSHIRTS-website-homepage-02">
        <image_tag("SAVEonSHIRTS_website_homepage_02.png")>
    </div>
    <div id="SAVEonSHIRTS-website-homepage-03">
        <image_tag("SAVEonSHIRTS_website_homepage_03.png")>
    </div>
```

Images are in the images folder under the assets folder.  However, images are still not showing up in localhost.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Elton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `erb`, if so you need to be using the `erb` scriptlet tags `<%= ... %>`

Example:

```
<%= image_tag("SAVEonSHIRTS_website_homepage_01.png") %>
```

Reference documentation: [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following

```
<%= image_tag("SAVEonSHIRTS_website_homepage_01.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round" , :width => "300") %>

alt => If image is not present then this message will be displayed
class => If you want to assign any class
width/hight => if you want to specify specify width and height .
```